# Find some family of transformation with the given constraints.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transformation, projection

I need to find some family of transformations that satisfies the following constraints:

1. Every transformation must be linear
2. All nonzero vectors transformed by all transformation in this family are eigenvectors
3. Given some transformation in the family satisfying a -> a' and d -> d', a' and b' must be related by some function f and d' and c' must be related by the same function f. This function can not change in the family.

[Picture of desired transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C5zD.jpg)

Is there any family of transformations which satisfies all of these conditions? If so what is it? If not why not? I can find a solution that satisfies any two conditions, but I can't seem to find one that satisfies all three.

Comment: When you say transformation, do you mean function $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$? More specifics would be helpful here.

Comment: Yes I do, what other specifics can I give?

Comment: 2. might need more explanation.

Comment: For any point P, P' must lie upon a line going through P and the origin